# in python can write below in single if condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

How can I rewrite the below code using only single if condition instead of two if
conditions in Python 3.7?

```
with open('demo.csv', 'r') as f, open("Result_csv.csv", 'w+') as out:
    for line in f:
        if '/tcp' in line:
            print(line)
            out.write(line)
        if '/udp' in line:
            print(line)
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: yes, just use an `or`. (Unless it's important to output the line twice if it contains both strings.)

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('demo.csv', 'r') as f, open("Result_csv.csv", 'w+') as out:
    for line in f:
        if '/tcp' in line or '/udp' in line:
            print(line)
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: thanks... its works....

Comment: please accept as solution if it works, upvoting helps ;)

Comment: By the way, the parentheses are unneeded.

Comment: yes i know. just to make it clearer ;)

Comment: The parentheses arguably make it less clear and also violate style guides, but it still works fine.

Comment: edited to keep us all happy :D

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regular expression to search multiple substrings.

```
import re
with open('demo.csv', 'r') as f, open("Result_csv.csv", 'w+') as out:
    for line in f:
        if re.search('/tcp|/udp', line):
            print(line)
            out.write(line)
```